# Active menu also for single array

Tags: menus

For our (new) website I figured out how to make menu's active. The only problem is that I want multiple pages, singles and categories under one active menu (just to remind people in what section they are).

How do I get this working?

Example: Below the menu gets the status 'active' when viewing the category-app-functies.php.

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li<?php if ( is_category('app-functies')) { echo ' class="current"'; } elseif ( is_singular( 'augmented-reality' )) { echo ' class="current"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/app-functies/">App Functies</a></li>      
      </ul>
```

Also when viewing url.com/app-functies/X/ I like to make the menu active aswell. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it out:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li<?php if ( is_category('app-functies')) { echo ' class="current"'; } elseif ( is_singular( 'augmented-reality' )) { echo ' class="current"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/app-functies/">App Functies</a></li>      
  </ul>
```

If you want to add more then 1 is_category() you can also use `is category('') || is_singular('')` .

Basic PHP knowledge.. but not for a designer like me. Hope this help a lot for other people as well.